# MATLAB symbolic expression

Tags: matlab, symbolic-math

I have two expressions which are T="x +B " and K="D*t+D*c" and "T=K" . I want to write this expression for just D  i.e. "D= (x+B)/t+c". Is there any function for this situation in MATLAB? My real expressions are not short which I gave as example.

Comment: Your example is not a very good one. The variable `D` can actually have *any* value as can be seen by rearranging: D*(x+B) = D*(t+c). In Matlab's Symbolic Math toolbox there's [`solve`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/solve.html). I recommend reading the documentation closely and trying the examples. Just note that it won't help you in cases where there are infinitely many solutions like your example or when there is no analytical solution.

Comment: I don't realize my example is wrong thank you for reminding and 'solve' solves my problem.